# How to implement model's read/unread property

Tags: django, design-patterns, solr, indexing

I'm writing a Django application where an user can view multiple `List` objects, which contains several `ListItem`s.

What I want is to keep track of of read/unread property for each `ListItem` object for each user. A `List` object is indexed using `Solr`.

I have one suggestion but I feel like it's not the ideal one.

1) Since each ListItem contains a timestamp when it was created. I could store the `last viewed` timestamp per `List/User` and query for all items in that list that are newer than this timestamp, that would allow me to get unread articles for a given user in a list.

What I don't like about this that some sites can keep track of (**r**)ead/(**u**)nread property where the list looks like this **ruuuururururuuur**. My solution can only mark articles from certain timestamp as read like **rrrrrrruuuuuu**.

2) I was also thinking about taking advantage of Solr index, but indexing user specific data that often is in my opinion definitely a bad idea. While browsing the net, I've also seen some suggestions to create a separate index for user related data? Would that be a way to go?

What is the best practice for implementing such a solution? Any help, suggestion or links to relevant articles would be appreciated.